# FromDefinition in camel 3.x - migration from 2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

Mgration from camel 2.x to 3.x. Before I used

```
route.getRouteContext()
.getFrom()
.getUri()
```

where route is `org.apache.camel.Route` . How can I do it in camel 3.x (to get to `FromDefinition` in camel 3.x) or at least could you tell me how can I search for methods in camel 3.x to see where they are placed now
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. It is;

```
route.getRouteContext()
                .getFrom()
                .getLabel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a bean based route? If thats the case, it was changed to the following format

```
route.from().to()
```

This guide may be very useful on your migration [Migrate from camel 2 to 3](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html)

Comment: What? As I said it is `org.apache.camel.Route` so you are wrong, there is nothing like .from()